# Freeware website monitoring and alert tool

Tags: gratis, web-apps, monitoring, hosted

I'm looking for a good freeware website for event performance, monitoring & alerting tool similar to [Alert-Site](https://smartbear.com/product/alertsite/web-monitoring/) (licensed & paid).

It should check/monitor websites, events, processes for down, hung or error state and send out emails.

I am able to live with the constraints a free tool has compared to licensed however, would appreciate suggestions of the benefits and popularity of the proposed freeware tool.

Comment: Try https://uptime.onl

Answer (score 1):

The [Uptime Robot](https://uptimerobot.com/) solution is the best solution in my experience.

You can contact with the [support team](https://uptimerobot.com/support) and they can add manually for your the **Distribution List Email** you need.

The basic plan is powerful enough to meet your needs and also exists a PRO plan to Custom **HTTP Headers** and **Statuses**.

And you can create a custom **Status Page** easely and totally free.

Comment: The way this is worded, are you affiliated with them?

Comment: I am a user of their services.

Answer (score 1):

If you need an active monitoring system with a solid Web and Restful support, flexible active metrics collection (allowing continuous blackbox availability testing) and server monitoring check https://monitis.com or https://cula.io/.

Comment: Monitis is not free. There is a 15-day full-featured FREE trial available.

Answer (score 0):

Windows PowerShell can scrape websites, using Invoke-WebRequest. This could involve a learning curve but has the advantage of being free, and can integrate email (I use it for checking for website updates etc). You could do some logic and timing eg (every 10min, if statuscode is NOT 200, then send an email)

```
Invoke-WebRequest www.google.com | select statuscode

Send-MailMessage -To john@savilltech.net" -Subject 'website is down' -from administrator@savilltech.net -smtpServer 'savdalex01.savilltech.net'
```

Comment: Perhaps sharing set tool would be beneficial for the community?

Comment: Even a simple, very basic PowerShell script to check if a site is up & send an email if not - not everyone is a coder ;-)